# React-Native Doctor can't find Android SDK

Tags: android, react-native

I am setting up my react-native development environment on Windows 10. I have installed Android Studio Giraffe, Android SDK Build tools (multiple versions corresponding with the API levels), Android SDK Command-line Tools (all versions), and Android SDK Platform Tools.

I have set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. I have added the platform-tools, build-tools, and cmdline-tools directories to the PATH environment variable.

I have a local.properties file (built by Android Studio) with the sdk.dir location specified.

When I run "npx react-native doctor" it still cannot find the Android SDK.

I have spent time going through several of the existing questions around this, but none of those solutions worked. Android Studio can run the app just fine as long as Metro is running, but I can't get the "npx react-native run-android" command to work until I sort this out.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of all the stupid things...it was because my username has a space in it and the react-native CLI didn't like that. That was it. I moved my Android Studio SDK installs to a different location and it worked.

Comment: my user name has not any space but i have this problem too!!!